# I can't get url of tab when this tab is closed in firefox sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In Sdk tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Track_a_single_tab

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

function onOpen(tab) {
  tab.on("close", logClose);
}

function logClose(tab) {
  console.log(tab.url + " is closed");
}

tabs.on('open', onOpen);
```

When I close tab, console say "undefined is closed";

And how to know the url of the tab when the tab is closed?

Comment: Is there a `unload` or `onbeforeunload` event? Something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload

Comment: I think you're callback is run slightly too late, and the tab object is there but properties like url and title are already gone by the time your callback fires - this is because they are getters.